# OCaml: applied to too many arguments

Tags: ocaml

Why the code

```
if some_bool_var then
begin
    output_string some_file "some string";   (* <--- error here *)
end
```

generates "applied to too many arguments" error. But if I change it to

```
if some_bool_var then output_string some_file "some string";
```

it compiles fine.

Why is it so?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty skeptical that what you've presented doesn't compile. I copied it into the top level and sure enough I'm not getting an error at all.

The problem is most likely not what you've typed but what is after what you've typed. I'm guessing you've got more lines of code for this particular function, thus `end` should have a semi-colon after it denoting the end of that command. Think of `begin ... end` as an alternative to `( ... )`, and `...;` as an alternative to `let () = ... in`. Thus, using `begin ... end` is not a replacement for the use of a semicolon.

Also, the semi-colon that ends your `output_string` call between `begin` and `end` is unnecessary since that block does not continue with more commands.

Comment: Yeah, my code is within much lines and this "semicolons magic" makes me wonder sometimes. While I was wating for an answer I faced another such problem which DID worked with "begin/end" and then I changed it to `( ... )` and it worked too. But when I returned to that one scope where previous single-line `if` was wrong - `( ... )` brackes did not helped me. But when I changed `)` to `);` - it worked. It all is veeery strange. Sometimes I need to taste several combinations to make project to compile. Anyway, this is working solution. Thank you!

Comment: It's really not at all that strange. and pretty natural when you fit your head into the paradigm that the language designers built from. Remember that everything returns a type (in your case `unit`) and it needs to be dealt with.